# How do I verify versions of Adobe?

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners, wireshark

I ran a vulnerability scan against a server and it is pulling back a lot of Adobe vulnerabilities. I ran a Wireshark capture on the scan but I can't seem to write up a Wireshark filter on the packets. Does anyone know how to look for the versions of Adobe in Wireshark? (or any tool that will remotely pull the versions would be helpful).

**edited. I did say Apache in my first question. I found the Apache article and had that stuck in my head when I wrote it. I need ADOBE versions.

Comment: Try sending a long request (e.g. `example.com/?AAAAAAAAAAA...` with 4000+ 'A's) to force a HTTP 414. Almost always leaks the version through such error responses.

Comment: [Adobe is one big vulnerability waiting to inflict itself upon you](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=adobe&search_type=all&cves=on). Okay, this is partially tongue in cheek (the software is very popular and complex)...

Comment: Please also be explicit in what you mean by "Adobe". There are a bunch of very different products.

Comment: What Adobe product, and what kind of 'vulnerability scan'?

Answer (score 1):

**It's EVERYWHERE... like a virus.**

[Adobe uses Apple's Bonjour service](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/bonjour-windows-cs3-cs4.html) also known as `mDNSResponder.exe` to communicate with the mother ship. [More about Bonjour here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002445-SW1). Adobe transfers things like licensing, usage, and error data. They also run a service called `armsvc.exe` which is the [Adobe Acrobat Update Service](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/disable-automatic-updates-acrobat-reader.html) that also calls home to check for updates periodically. Adobe has a [video about how to remove mDNSReponsder](http://tv.adobe.com/en/watch/the-support-report/renaming-and-removing-the-bonjour-service/) on their TV site.

If you're running a Creative Suite on your server (not likely, but not unheard of) you'll also get traffic from different plug-ins in various apps that connect to web services, also anything that uses the Creative Cloud will also likely transfer data and try to authenticate a license, as well as all web programs like Dreamweaver, Muse, and Flash obviously.

If this is a Windows box, you can use [sysinternals process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check for different running apps and the company name of the owner of the process. If it's a Mac server then you can open activity monitor to see what's running, in addition to `top` via command line.